# PHP why is not "strtotime is not defined"

Tags: php, strtotime

```
// why does this not work PHP in XAMMP stack
// error: "strtotime is not defined"

$date2 = strtotime('2010-10-01');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://www.php.net/manual/en/calendar.installation.php,

> To get these functions to work, you
> have to compile PHP with
> --enable-calendar.
>
> The Windows version of PHP has
> built-in support for this extension.
> You do not need to load any additional
> extensions in order to use these
> functions.

or on OS X:

> sudo port install php5-calendar

Failing that, try looking for php5-calendar in your system's package manager.

Comment: of course it help if you are in php tags not script tags -duh

Comment: although you accepted my answer, it is probably not the solution. I incorrectly was looking at the PHP Calendar package, not the Date/Time package, which is built in to pretty much all PHP installations.